# How can I fix erroos.rename() error [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Tags: python, docker, operating-system, rename

I'm trying to rename a file and append the datetime to the file name:

```
current_date = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

os.rename(r'C:\Users\xxx\test.csv',
          r'C:\Users\xxx\test__' + str(current_date) + '.csv')
```

error:

```
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
```

I also tried:

```
current_date = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

old = 'C:/Users/xxx/test.csv'
new = 'C:/Users/xxx/test_' + str(current_date) + '.csv'
os.rename(old, new)
```

Still got the same error, can someone help me please. This script will run in a docker container, I suspect if I can't rename a local file, can I just rename it in the docker image? But I assume the datetime part will be more complicated. I've been struggling for a whole week now. Can someone help me thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the colons that are the likely problem.
Replace:

current_date = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y_%m_%d_%H:%M:%S')

with:

current_date = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S')

You shouldn't have colons or spaces in a filename ideally.

Comment: Thanks, this solved the problem. Just a small follow up question, what other approaches I can use if I don't want to include my local path in the code (can I rename it in docker?)

Comment: You can use relative paths instead of explicit path so like "./test/test.csv" to use the folder above or "../test/test.csv" for two folders above your current position in the directory path

Comment: Ah it works, but how can I reference this new filename in the future codes, currently they're hard-coded with the previous name, but since I appended the current datetime, I can't hardcode the changing datetime anymore.

Comment: import csv
with open('./test/test.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
     spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
     for row in spamreader:
           print(', '.join(row))